# Cannot find RIPEMD160 in .net core

Tags: .net, .net-core, hash

I can't find any implementation of **RIPEMD160** in .net core 3.1.

The [MS documentation for RIPEMD160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ripemd160?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netstandard-2.1) does not exist for net *Standard*, ***Core 3.1***, *Core 5.0* .

In *System.Security.Cryptography* I can't find nothing related to it.

Before looking to third party packages (maybe [Chilkat](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChilkatDnCore/)) I'd like to try to use a framework library.

Comment: It seems they didn't import it (not even the `RIPEMD160Managed` that was fully managed, so OS-independant)

Comment: I'm already importing BouncyCastle in the project. I foud _Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.RipeMD160Digest_ so will try to use this.

Comment: You could import the mono version mono had before merging the referencesource from Microsoft... https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-4.0.0-branch/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography/RIPEMD160Managed.cs (in this way you would bypass licensing problems... mono was licensed as MIT at that time... unclear what happened with the source they imported from referencessource)

Comment: Mmmh even the reference source is MIT licensed... so you can take the Microsoft "original" version: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/ripemd160managed.cs (see licensing notes https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource)

Comment: I've rolled back your question to an earlier version. If you want to provide a solution to your question please post a separate answer to it. You can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft decided to remove "managed" (fully implemented in .NET) implementations of hashing and crypto algorithms in .NET Core (don't ask me why). See for example https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2094 (that is exactly about RIPEMD160):

> RIPEMD160 is not an algorithm that is provided by the OS crypto layers, and .NET Core no longer carries managed implementations of cryptographic algorithms.

And from [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography):

> All hash algorithm and hash-based message authentication (HMAC) classes, including the *Managed classes, defer to the OS libraries. While the various OS libraries differ in performance, they should be compatible.

I can't find if there was a discussion about this, or if some manager decided that it was best to do in this way or what.

A simple solution is to grab the code used in .NET 4.7/.NET 4.8 and use it directly:

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/ripemd160managed.cs

The code is sourced as MIT, so there are no problems of licensing, see the [homepage](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource):

> The files in this repository are licensed under the MIT license unless otherwise specified in the file header. If the file header only contains a copyright header (e.g., "Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.", you can assume the associated file to be MIT-licensed.

Comment: Works. But I forgot to change an old implementation from:            //return (RIPEMD160)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("System.Security.Cryptography.RIPEMD160");

        
To:
return new VSSM.API.OMServicev3.CodeOld.RIPEMD160Managed();

Answer (score 1):

I started to copy some classes from [System.Security.Cryptography](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/ripemd160managed.cs) but because there are many attributes and dependencies on other classes/interfaces I don't like that solution.
Because Chilkat seems a little bit old (netstandard 1.3) and in the project I was already using [BouncyCastle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.NetCore) so in the end  I just wrote this:

```ml
type RIPEMD160 () =
    static member ComputeHash (bytes: byte array) =
        let hasher =  Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.RipeMD160Digest()
        hasher.BlockUpdate(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        let hash:byte array = Array.zeroCreate (hasher.GetDigestSize())
        hasher.DoFinal(hash, 0) |> ignore
        hash
```